# Inserting text between prev next buttons using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the following script in place and have the functionality for the previous and next buttons working perfectly. However, I received a request to insert the date in between the buttons so that it looks like this:

```
btnPrev issueDate btnNext
<     Date     >
```

Here's the code I have so far. I added the following in between the PREV and NEXT buttons, but it's not rendering on the page. How can I insert text in between those two buttons?

```
            type: "span",
            textContent: "November 1, 2022",
            ...this.btnIssue,
        });
```

Here's the entire script:

```
    constructor(selector, options = {}) {
        Object.assign(
            this, {
                EL: document.querySelector(selector),
                page: 0,
                selector,
                // btnTabs: {}, // Custom attributes for tabs (navigation) buttons
                btnPrev: {}, // Custom attributes for PREV button
                btnNext: {}, // Custom attributes for NEXT button
                classActive: "is-active",
                onChange: () => {},
            },
            options
        );
        this.EL_pages = this.EL.children;
        this.EL_pagination = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-tabs-pagination="${this.selector}"]`);
        this.EL_navigation = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-tabs-navigation="${this.selector}"]`);
        this.total = this.EL_pages.length;
        this.EL_prev = this._ELNew("button", {
            type: "button",
            textContent: "<",
            onclick: () => this.prev(),
            ...this.btnPrev,
        });
        this.EL_issue = this._ELNew("span", {
            type: "span",
            textContent: "November 1, 2022",
        });
        this.EL_next = this._ELNew("button", {
            type: "button",
            textContent: ">",
            onclick: () => this.next(),
            ...this.btnNext,
        });
        this.EL_buttons = Array.from(Array(this.total)).reduce((arr, _, i) => {
            const EL_btn = this._ELNew("button", {
                type: "button",
                textContent: i + 1,
                onclick: () => (this._page = i),
                ...this.btnPagination,
            });
            arr.push(EL_btn);
            return arr;
        }, []);
        this._init();
    }

    // Utility function - New element
    _ELNew = (sel, attr) => Object.assign(document.createElement(sel), attr || {});

    // Fix negative modulo index 
    _mod = (n) => ((n % this.total) + this.total) % this.total;

    // Initialize
    _init() {
        // Append nav buttons to DOM
        this.EL_pagination.forEach((EL) => EL.append(...this.EL_buttons));
        this.EL_navigation.forEach((EL) => EL.append(this.EL_prev, this.EL_next));

        // Set current page
        this._page = this.page;
    }

    prev(n = 1) {
        this._page -= n;
        return this;
    }

    next(n = 1) {
        this._page += n;
        return this;
    }

    show(idx) {
        this._page = idx;
        return this;
    }

    set _page(n) {
        this.page = this._mod(n);
        [...this.EL_pages, ...this.EL_buttons].forEach((EL) => EL.classList.remove(this.classActive));
        [this.EL_pages[this.page], this.EL_buttons[this.page]].forEach((EL) => EL.classList.add(this.classActive));
        // Provide a callback
        this.onChange.call(this);
    }

    get _page() {
        return this.page;
    }
}


// Use like:
const mySectionTabs = new Tabs("#issue-nav", {
    onChange() {
        console.clear();
        console.log(`Current page index: ${this.page}`);
    }
});
```

Comment: You've stated a requirement, but no actual question. What have you tried?

Comment: @ScottMarcus - I added more detail to the original post.

Comment: See in _init where it appends this.EL_prev, this.EL_next?  I'd guess you want to throw this.EL_issue (or whatever the element is containing the date) in between those.

Comment: @James - I just noticed that and updated it... right before seeing your comment, but appreciate the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had inadvertently left out "this.EL_issue" and have now updated it.

```js
this.EL_navigation.forEach((EL) => EL.append(this.EL_prev, this.EL_issue, this.EL_next));
```